# How to set an index range from a "startday" to an "endday" and cycle through the DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to assign an index that will begin at X and end at Y.

For example:

```
startday -01.01.2012,
endday - 31.02.2012.
```

Another DataFrame mimics 14 stock orders during that period of time with the following columns:
Date, Ticker, Stock Amount, Price (closing price), Value (`orders_df.Amount * orders_df.Price`).

I'm looking to calculate the end of day value of the portfolio (cash + stock value), starting cash equals 1,000,000.

I'm not sure how to assign the index for the DataFrame  (for the first DataFrame) for the entire period. So far I was able to calculate on the portfolio value for the 14 days of stock orders.

```
cash.append(1000000)
cash = pd.Series(index=timestamps)
day = startday
for i in orders_df.Date:
    if i == day:
        cash = cash + orders_df.Value
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused, first you append something to cash then you reassign it to an empty series. Are you sure this is the same as your code? Is it possible to include an example with the first few lines of the DataFrame (`df.head()`) you have and the DataFrame you would like?

Comment: The "Orders" DataFrame is as follows Date (2012-31-2011), Ticker (AAPL), Action (Buy/Sell), Quantity (1000 stocks), Price (Closing price of the trading day), Value (Price X Amount). The second Dataframe im trying to create will include in the index the Date (from starday - to endday) and one column which will be equal to the value of cash. If we start with 100 dollars for example and the orders is to buy stock worth $50 then the cash value at that day will be $50. I'm very new to python and therefore my code may not be efficient or correct at all and I apologize for that.

Comment: ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'XOM', 'IBM']
   variable 'close' is  <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>     object class
                   Date Ticker Action  Amount  Prices  C      Value
    0   2011-01-10 16:00:00   AAPL    Buy    1500  340.99 -1   -511485.00
    1   2011-01-13 16:00:00   AAPL   Sell    1500  344.20  1  516300.00
    2   2011-01-13 16:00:00    IBM    Buy    4000  144.55 -1 -578200.00
    3   2011-01-26 16:00:00   GOOG    Buy    1000  616.50 -1 -616500.00